# On emit event: Expected a spy, but got Function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

I run this test but I get this error:

`Unhandled Promise rejection: <toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got Function.`

```
  it('should change myComponent value', () => {
     spyOn(component.mychange, 'emit');
     const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#mychange')).nativeElement;
     input.value = "2";
     fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
       expect(component.mychange.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
     });
   });
```

There are similar questions, but it happens to me on an emit event, I tried the solutions of those questions but they don't work.

Comment: What happens if u assign the spyOn to a variable and use that in the when stable?

Comment: Error: Expected spy emit to have been called with: [ 2 ] but it was never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See you are setting up a spy on emit method here -
spyOn(component.mychange, 'emit');

Problem seems to be with triggering of the change -

so you would need to call component.mychange(10);

So your code would become

```
it('should change myComponent value', async () => {
     spyOn(component.mychange, 'emit');
     const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#mychange')).nativeElement;
     input.value = "2";
     component.mychange(2);
     await fixture.whenStable()
     expect(component.mychange.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
   });
```

Please also I have used async await which makes it much better!!

Comment: You're right, but that emit happens directly in HTML, it's not wrapped in a function, so at this point I'm really wondering if this test is right... I guess it just doesn't have to.

Comment: OK. Just given it a second thought. You must remove component.mychange(2);
and call input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); can you give it a try?